# How to decide which kind of my application is ?(java rich internet application)

Tags: java, applet

what is the basic difference b/w an applet application & a web start application? What is the meaning of running in context of a browser? According to my observation both applet & web start runs in context of abrowser but according oracle documentation web start do not run in context of a browser? Could anyone please explain in detail.... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Applets run inside of a browser, using a plugin, controlled by an HTML applet tag. This is similar to a Flash movie.

Web Start applications are loaded from the Internet, and run in somewhat sandboxed environment, but they are basically standalone desktop applications.

Comment: What is the sandboxed environment> Do you mean to say that apllication runs in other window which starts after requesting url in browser? kindly explain

Comment: The browser just downloads the app deployment file. After that it is its own process, completely independent of the browser. You can even start it from your desktop after the first time. Sandbox: there are checks that the app is properly signed, and things like file system access can be restricted. But the sandbox allows for much more than an applet could do.

Comment: The explanation in [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)] & [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start] confuesd me as i am thinking my apllication is a web start apllication which use a sandbox which does not support jnlp, as we don't have main class . Like this any web start application exist? kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Web start applications are delivered via http, but don't need a browser to run. Applets however run in the context of the web browser.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start for an extensive explanation.

Comment: When we request url it must be in browser, Do you mean to say that after url requset web start doesn't need the browser? kindly explain

Comment: Yes, after starting, it is an independent process.

Comment: Thanks a lot again Olaf dietsche. Now According to above explanation and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start i can confirm that my apllication is a webstart but in my clent code there no .jnlp file nor main class. we have only run() in almost all .java file.And it is some time being said by my manager that we don't support because some defect that is created by enabling new plug in.If my apllication doesnot support jnlp then how it is a webstart application? as everything apart from location of main class my apllication works as jnlp. Kindly help...

Comment: The explanation in [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)] & [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start] confuesd me as i am thinking my apllication is a web start apllication which use a sandbox which does not support jnlp, as we don't have main class . Like this any web start application exist? kindly help

Comment: @Pankaj I'm not familiar with Java Web Start beyond the wikipedia page. What I conclude from the description is, that the jnlp xml file describes, where the client finds the application and several other requirements. AFAICS, there's no need for a plugin beyond java. The only requirement from server side, seems to be to deliver the proper MIME type. So, whatever works for you or doesn't, I don't know.

Comment: @Pankaj: Feel free to open another question for these follow-ups. And please keep them specific.